# How to hide pages in a streamlit multiple page app?

Tags: python, user-interface, web-applications, show-hide, streamlit

I have developed a Streamlit app with multiple pages using the sidebar. My objective is to implement a mechanism where clicking on one page in the sidebar will hide the other pages. I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve this behavior effectively. Could you please provide assistance or suggestions for implementing this functionality?

I've created a Streamlit app with multiple pages, but currently, when I click on one page, the sidebar persists on other pages. I want to modify this behavior so that clicking on one page hides the sidebar on other pages.
This is the code:

```
enter code here

def run():
    with st.sidebar:
        app = option_menu(
            menu_title="pondering",
            options=['Account','Trending','Your Posts','About'],
                    default_index=1)
    if app == 'Account':
        account.app()
    if app == 'home':
        home.app()
    if app == 'Trending':
        trending.app()
    if app == 'Your Posts':
        your_posts.app()
    if app == 'About':
        about.app()
    run()
```

Comment: you have wrong indentation - you execute `run()` inside `def run()`

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't hide the page right?

Comment: comments don't have to resolve problems. We use comments to show other problems, ask for details, etc.

Comment: That too helped me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following custom function and call it in the first line of the pages functions where you want to hide the sidebar.

```
def hide_sidebar():
    st.markdown("""
    <style>
        section[data-testid="stSidebar"][aria-expanded="true"]{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    """, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Example:

```
def home():
    hide_sidebar() 
    ...
```

If you don't want to use a function, you will have to copy the `markdown` and paste it in all your pages.

Comment: Ok @JITHIN, I hope that was helpful

Comment: S, it helped me to hide pages but now I am getting new error like page mix-up when multiple users are working on it.